# jquery mobile doesn't load dialogues with page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use jquery mobile for navigation and to display a dialog. Whenever I load the target page directly (enter "target.html" in browser) and press the button to display a dialog everything works fine. But when I start at the navigation page (start.html), navigate by clicking the link and then press the button for the dialog, nothing happens, no dialog opens, it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure that this is due to the AJAX-way of loading the page in jquery.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--start.html-->
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="target.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Go</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- target.html -->
<head>
  <title>Target</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="address-sender-page">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <a href="#myDialog">Open dialog</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="dialog" id="myDialog">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p>Dialog</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This could be a bug in jquery, but I guess it's my fault. Any idea how to fix this? Is it documented in jquery mobile docs?

Comment: jQM 1.4.x no longer supports dialogs. Instead you can either load a regular page as a dialog or use popups. Depending on what you are trying to do, probably the popup widget is what you want: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/

Comment: Thanks, that helped.